# Log file size check and log writing using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to log error in a web application designed in asp.net webforms.

Currently i use following code to log error when ever exception is raised

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 

        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs


            Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

            // Include enterprise logic for logging exceptions 
            // Get the absolute path to the log file 
            string logFile = "~/App_Data/ErrorLog.txt";
            logFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logFile);

            // Open the log file for append and write the log
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("********** {0} **********", DateTime.Now);
                if (exc.InnerException != null)
                {
                    sw.Write("Inner Exception Type: ");
                    sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.GetType().ToString());
                    sw.Write("Inner Exception: ");
                    sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.Message);
                    //sw.Write("Inner Source: ");
                    sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.Source);
                    if (exc.InnerException.StackTrace != null)
                    {
                      //  sw.WriteLine("Inner Stack Trace: ");
                      //  sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.StackTrace);
                    }
                }

                sw.Write("Exception Type: ");
                sw.WriteLine(exc.GetType().ToString());
                sw.WriteLine("Exception: " + exc.Message);
                // sw.WriteLine("Source: " + source);
                //sw.WriteLine("Stack Trace: ");
                if (exc.StackTrace != null)
                {
                 //   sw.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
                  //  sw.WriteLine();
                }
                // sw.Close();
            }

    }
```

How can i modify this code so that i can check the file size first to see if it has reached 1MB size. If logfile has reached the 1MB size then i will create another file with date label etc.

Comment: you can use FileInfo to check the file size

Answer (score 2):

You can use FileInfo in this way:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(logFile);
if(fi.length > 1024) {
    // create new file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a powerful logging library such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). It allows you to specify [maximum file size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743051/2780791) for a log file and also to automatically [delete old files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068788/nlog-delete-logs-older-than-x-days).

As you can see, these options and many other are automatically handled based on a xml configuration.